# Can React Helmet inject a javascript object into <HEAD> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, head, helmet.js

I've a question, I need to inject into the **HEAD** tag a javascript object, for tag management purposes.
This is my **Helmet** component, but it accepts only specific parameters to set to metadata serverside through rewind() function.

Is there a way still to use React Helmet to do what I need, so, create javascritpt objects into a **SCRIPT** tag or should I follow a different approach?

**MyComponent.js**

```
<Helmet
    title={article.get('title')}
    meta={[
        {"property": "og:title", "content": article.get('title')},
        {"property": "og:url", "content": article.get('url')},

        {"property": "twitter:title", "content": article.get('title')}
    ]}
/>
```

**server.js**

```
let htmlHead = `
  ${head.title}
  ${head.meta.toString()}
`;
```

Thank you for the support

Answer (score 25):

Th existing answers are outdated. You don't need to contort the code with `script` attributes or `innerHTML`. You can use the `<script>` tag as usual in HTML:

```html
<Helmet>
  <script src="https://some.host/api.js" type="text/javascript" />
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score 18):

**Update**

This answer from 2017 applies for v3 of react-helmet, and is now a little outdated - there's now a better way to do this, using a script tag directly, as referenced in a [newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562235/1082449), which I'd recommend doing instead.

Will keep this answer up for posterity, and for people on older versions of Helmet. But just a note that though it's the top voted answer, it's no longer the best answer.

---

> I need to inject into the HEAD tag a javascript object

You could define the object in an inline script, using the `innerHTML` attribute on Helmet's `script` prop - this attribute was introduced in [Helmet 3.0.0](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/65#issuecomment-201403040)

```
<Helmet 
  script={[{ 
    type: 'text/javascript', 
    innerHTML: 'window.yourObject = { it: "works" }' 
  }]} 
/>
```

Comment: if you have a json object you can use like .

`
<Helmet 
  script={[{ 
    type: 'text/javascript', 
    innerHTML: JSON.stringify(  { it: "works" } )
  }]} 
/>
`

Answer (score 12):

If I understood your question correctly, in your `<Helmet/>` declaration, you can add in a `script` property to inject a `<script>` tag into the HTML head of your pages.

```
<Helmet
    title={article.get('title')}
    meta={[
        {"property": "og:title", "content": article.get('title')},
        {"property": "og:url", "content": article.get('url')},

        {"property": "twitter:title", "content": article.get('title')}
    ]}
    script={[
            {"src": "http://url.com/script.js", "type": "text/javascript"}
    ]}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add a script tag in following way:

```
<Helmet>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {`console.log("Hello World");window.secret = "Tss..."`}
    </script>
</Helmet>
```